# Display native "Add Products" popup screen in custom lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom

I will really appreciate if anyone can advise on the requirement below.

I have a requirement in a custom lightning component to redirect to the native create new opportunity record page and add products pop up (which pops up automatically when an opportunity is created).

I have used $A.get("e.force:createRecord") to call create opportunity page and its working fine but unable to call "Add Products" pop up automatically right after opportunity is created. Is this possible or is there any way to display product selector on the success of opportunity creation after createRecord.fire(); in the existing method below?

Existing function to redirect to the create opportunity page

```
invoke : function (component,event,helper){

    var createRecord = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecord.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Opportunity"
    });
    createRecord.fire();
}
```

[image: Popop which I have to show]